# Is there a way to find functions specifically with $n$ zeros?

Tags: functions

I was reading about some root-finding algorithms and wondered if there is a way to find functions specifically with n zeros, for example: finding a function (or a set of functions) that has 378 zeros. Is that possible?

Comment: $f(x)=(x-a)(x-b)(x-c)$ has its zeros at?

Comment: Consider polynomial functions...

Comment: $f(x)=0$ if $x \in \{1,2,3,..., 378 \}$ and $f(x)=1$ otherwise....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

$$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{378}(x-k)$$

Comment: Can you provide a little more about it?

Comment: @Gustavo: If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ is any finite set of real numbers, $$f(x)=\prod_{k=1}^n(x-a_k)$$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ whose roots are precisely the numbers $a_1,\dots,a_n$.

Comment: Everytime I think I'm going to ask something mathematically challenging, there comes Brian and answer it in 0,004sec. Haha

Answer (score 7):

Brian has given the obvious answer, but it occurs to me that there are probably a lot of other ways to answer the question.  For example, consider $$f_k(x) = \sin x + \frac xk.$$

Since $-1\le\sin x\le 1$, all the zeroes of this function lie between $-k$ and $k$.  In this interval, $\sin x$ has $2\left\lfloor \frac k\pi\right\rfloor+1$ zeroes. Adding the $\frac xk$ term moves those zeroes around, but does not eliminate them.

[image: graph of sin(x) + x/6pi]

So by adjusting $k$ suitably, you can find a function in this family with any odd number of zeroes; for even numbers of zeroes use $\cos x + \frac xk$ instead.

Comment: Great answer! +1